# Prolog office puzzle

Tags: prolog, typeerror, clpfd, zebra-puzzle

I'm attempting to do a Prolog assignment for school, and basically it's trying to find out who has what office. The question is:

*Hunter, Laura, Jim, Sally, and Jack work in the same building with five adjacent offices. Hunter doesn’t work in the 5th office and Laura doesn’t work in the first office. Jim doesn’t work in the first or last office, and he is not in an office adjacent to Jack or Laura. Sally works in some office higher than Laura’s. Who works in what offices?*

So what I have is the code below, but I'm receiving:

```
uncaught exception: error(type_error(fd_evaluable,abs/1),(#\=)/2)
```

Here is the code.

```
puzzle(P) :-
        findWhosOffice(P,Z),
        labeling([],Z).

findWhosOffice(P, Z) :-
        P = [hunter-Hunter, jack-Jack, jim-Jim, laura,Laura,sally,Sally],
        Z = [Hunter, Laura, Jim, Sally, Jack],

        Hunter #\= 5,
        Laura #\= 1,
        Jim #\= 1,
        Jim #\= 5,
        abs(Jim-Jack) #\=1,
        abs(Jim-Laura) #\=1,
        Sally #> Laura.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not defined the domain for the variables in `Z`. There is also one constraint that's missing to make it a valid and unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I see that you have not used all_different():

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

puzzle(Employee,Employee_Office_Room):-
    Employee=[Hunter, Laura, Jim, Sally, Jack], Employee ins 1..5,
    Employee_Office_Room=[First,_Second,_Third,_Fourth,Fifth], Employee_Office_Room ins 1..5,
    all_different(Employee),
    all_different(Employee_Office_Room),
    
    Hunter#\=Fifth,
    Laura#\=First,
    Jim#\=First,
    Jim#\=Fifth,
    not_nextto(Jim,Laura),
    not_nextto(Jim,Jack),
    Sally#=Laura-1,
    labeling([],Employee),labeling([],Employee_Office_Room).
    
    not_nextto(A,B):-abs(A-B)#\=1.

?-puzzle(Employee,Employee_Office_Room).
Employee = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5],
Employee_Office_Room = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Employee = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5],
Employee_Office_Room = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
Employee = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5],
Employee_Office_Room = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
Employee = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5],
Employee_Office_Room = [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
Employee = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5],
Employee_Office_Room = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]....
```